# MST: define model with children of itself

Tags: mobx-state-tree

Just started to fiddle around with Mobx-state-tree.

I have this model, that has `parent` and `children` properties that can be filled with instances of the same model.

So basically something like this:

```js
const Page = types.model({
    guid: types.string,
    title: types.string,
    description: types.string,
    parent: types.union(Page, types.undefined),
    children: types.array(Page),
})
```

But, obviously `Page` is not available yet on the creation of this model.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After minutely reading the docs, I found the answer. Using `types.late()`:

```js
const Page = types.model({
    guid: types.string,
    title: types.string,
    description: types.string,
    parent: types.union(types.late(() => Page), types.undefined),
    children: types.optional(types.array(types.late(() => Page)), []),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this and having trouble finding the documentation, additional details regarding the Mobx-state-tree `types.lazy` see the [API `late` documentation](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#late)

> `types.late` - Defines a type that gets implemented later. This is useful when you have to deal with circular dependencies. Please notice that when defining circular dependencies TypeScript isn't smart enough to inference them.

```js
import { type IAnyModelType, type Instance, types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

// TypeScript isn't smart enough to infer self referencing types.
const Node = types.model({
    children: types.array(types.late((): IAnyModelType => Node)) // then typecast each array element to Instance<typeof Node>
})

type INode = Instance<typeof Node>
```

Source: https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#late